# Difference between database, table, column collation

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, collation

I understand that collations are a set of rules for making comparisons over a character set. MySQL / MariaDB has table and database collations in addition to column collation. I was wondering what was the difference between a collation on these three (database, table and column).

Thanks.

Comment: What should `SELECT 'e' = 'é'` return? Without a table to reference, there has to be some "higher" collation, right?

Comment: Don't forget about server collation, which is set (or uses the default) during the connection handshake between the server and the client.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

MySQL's character sets and collations can be interpreted as a top-down list of prioritized items. The topmost is least priority and the bottommost is most priority.

Order of precedence with topmost being least precedence:

- Server collation
- Connection-specific collation
- Database collation
- Table collation
- Column collation
- Query collation (using `CAST` or `CONVERT`)

The *server collation* is set by the server, which is set either inside of `my.cnf` or when the server was built from source code. By default, this will usually be `latin1` or `utf8`, depending on your platform.

The *connection-specific collation* is set by the client using a query like `SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci';`. Most clients don't set a connection-specific collation, so the server will use its own default as explained above.

The *database collation* is set during database creation, or manually by updating it later. If you don't specify one, it will use the next higher-level collation, which would either be the connection-specific or the server collation.

The *table collation* is the same as the database collation, except if left blank, it will use the database as its default, then connection-specific, and then finally the server's collation.

The *column collation* uses the table's collation as its default, and if there is no collation set, it will then follow up the chain to find a collation to use, stopping at server if all of the others weren't set.

The *query collation* is specified in the query by using `CAST` or `CONVERT`, but otherwise will use the next available collation in the chain. There's no way to set this unless you use a function.

Please also refer to the manual page [Character Set Support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset.html).

Answer (score 5):

In short. When you set Server collation. to UTF-8. All Databases created without defining collation will inherit it from Server.

```
column iherits from table
table inherits from database
database inherits from server
```

However, you can overwrite default server at one of those points. Then everything will inherit from it.

Comment: Your answer was good too thanks but I marked the other one because it gave more information I found useful. Thanks!

Comment: if I alter the table's collation, would it update all the columns collation (if not specified)?

Comment: Nope. Inheritance is only applied at creation. If you modify table, then new columns will get new collation, but old ones will stay as they were.